# Rotating 5D cube with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got 2x 5D cubes in the shape of `[1, 4, 21, 302, 302]` that I need to compare with each other. However the first is rotated with respect to the second. 
If I work with just these two images I can fix it by applying `np.rot90(np.flipud(a))` to the left image, with a being that `302x302` image. 
How do I apply this to the entire cube without changing the other axes?

[image]

Comment: Some code snippet would perhaps help to get more attention :)

Comment: `flipud` just does `arr[::-1, ...]`.  You could apply that flip any of the other axes.  `rot90` takes an `axes` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the image like you're describing it is simply transposing/swapping the two axes x and y. For a single image in a 2D array, you would simply do

```
img.T
```

And for a 5D tensor like yours where the image is contained in the last two axes, you would do

```
img.transpose(0, 1, 2, 4, 3)
```